# Unable to login to steam ; Steam is having trouble connecting to the servers

Tags: login, connection, steam

Since Steam came out on Ubuntu (official) I've installed it and tried to log in but it didnt work at that time. I thought the servers were offline and I would try it later again.

Steam is giving me the following error message :

"Steam is having trouble connecting to the Steam servers".

Some weeks have passed now but I'm still not able to log in.
I've researched a lot of things and it is definitely not my router blocking steam, because I'm running a double boot and I'm perfectly able to run steam on my Windows 8 version.

As I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and the world of Linux I wonder if there is any integrated firewall in Ubuntu that may be blocking this, or does someone else have any suggestions or even better ; solution(s), to my problem.

I'm currently running on Ubuntu 12.10 and I've installed the most recent version of Steam via the Ubuntu software center. I've tried reinstalling it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem under 13.04.

Finally, it was that I'd typed wrong the password. Enter in the steam page and check you're writing the password right.